# Vectorize Function over Groups

Tags: pandas, grouping

I have some values (X) that belong to various groups (G). I would like (N) to divide each value by the maximum value in the group, as shown in this table:

[image]

I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7],
                   'G': [1,   1,   1,   2,   2,   2  ]})

def fun (X):
    Norm = 1 / max(X)
    return X * Norm

f = np.vectorize(fun, otypes=[float])

df['N']   = f(df['X']).groupby('G')
```

but this gives:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df['N'] = df['X']/df.groupby('G')['X'].transform('max')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df['N']  = df.groupby('G')['X'].apply(lambda x: x / x.max())
```